# dynamic casimir effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect

A few years ago, when i studied the casimir effect interpretation as the filtering out of vacuum modes with appropiate boundary conditions, i had the following dilemma; supposedly the derivation of the force between the walls was **entirely** equivalent to just calculating Van der Waals forces. This, as it was argued, compelled us to not take too seriously the idea of a negative energy density of the space between the walls.

However, i was left wondering what would happen if one would take the interpretation based on vacuum modes a bit further, and we could somehow switch on and off the permitivity $\epsilon$ of the conductor; what sort of long range radiation we would expect to see? 
A possible experimental implementation would be if the layers where superconductive, and then a magnetic field would be switched on just to break the superconductive phase.

We probably need to use the Dirac-Heisenberg-Wigner formalism for these sort of dynamic quantum systems, but what would be intuitively expected to be detected?

Comment: to be clear, this is NOT the sort of dynamic casimir effect i'm after in this question, but definitely worth a read: http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4714 in particular, it is interesting that they are modulating the inductance with a SQUID, which is not the same but it is quite related to the permittivity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A friend recently brought to my attention that this experiment was actually performed 6 months after i posted the question in this site:

http://blogs.nature.com/news/2011/11/light_coaxed_from_nothingness.html

http://www.chalmers.se/en/news/pages/chalmers-scientists-create-light-from-vacuum.aspx

Christopher Wilson from Chalmers (and his team) used the same mechanism that i've proposed in here: using a superconducting magnet to oscillate the mirror surface.

I'm glad to see that the idea really works!